# NSDictionary serialization into NSString

Tags: ios, serialization, nsdictionary, nsdata

I'm using URLScheme and I need to send serialized NSDictionary from my app A to my app B.

In the **app A**, I'm using NSKeyedArchiver to serialize my NSDictionary into a NSData

```
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is value 1", @"key1", 
                                    @"value 2", @"key2",
                                    @"value3", @"key3", 
                                    @"", @"key4", 
                                    @"value5", @"key5", 
                                    @"value 6", @"key6", 
                                    nil];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:myDictionary];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [archiver release];

    NSString *bytes = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                             encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

In the **app B**, I'm using NSKeyedUnarchiver

```
NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", val] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];        
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[unarchiver decodeObject] retain];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
[unarchiver release];
```

My serialized NSDictionary looks like:

> bplist00Ô01T$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiverÑR$0¯
>   !"#$%&'()U$nullÓ ZNS.objectsWNS.keysV$class¦
>   ¦Tkey2Tkey5Tkey3Tkey1Tkey6Tkey4Wvalue 2o@

And it looks like I can't convert this NSString to NSData and get my NSDictionary back.

NSData is NULL after the [dataUsingEncoding:dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why on earth are you sending bytes as a `NSString` - that's never going to work!

(a) `NSString` is for encoded textual data - i.e. data that follows a specific set of rules.

(b) `NSData` is for a series of bytes that are just bytes.

You have (b), not (a).

Send `NSData` objects and don't convert to/from `NSString` at all.

---

EDIT what about URL paramters?

OK, so my answer above was a little too black and white.

If you *really* need to convert between data and string, take a look at base64 encoding - it will give you a safe string representation of your data at the expense of size.

There's a few libraries outt here that can convert for you - try this one : https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

However, what will happen if you encode a dictionary on an iOS6 device and decode it on iOS5 - you can't be 100% certain that will work. You might be better off writing your own coding/decoding methods that convert the dictionary to a string and back again. If it's for a URL, why not just use URL parameters i.e. `x=5&name=Bob`?

Comment: Can you explain how I can manage to send NSData into a NSURL to launch and retrieve parameters from an app A to an app B ? thanks

Comment: I'm using URLScheme, that's why I need to send my NSDictionary as a NSString

Comment: Actually, I already tried to format my NSDictionary as get parameters and it worked. But I wanted to manage more complex NSDictionary that is why I tried to figure out how to serialize NSDictionary into NSString ;)
I will try your Base64 encoding solution. Thanks

Comment: Why not write a method in a category of NSDictionary that converts any dictionary to a GET parameter string - then your dictionary complexity won't matter :) You could always open source it when you are done . . . ;)

Comment: Just tried and it worked. Thanks a lot! So you think there are some possible workaround to manage depending on iOS version?

Comment: Not really - if iOS6 uses different encoding then there's not much iOS 5 can do about that! You will judt have to test and hope Apple are working to a standard that will be backwards compatible between iOS versions. You could also look at @TraustiThor 's answer - a JSON string is a pretty good idea, after you've percent escaped any special characters you might have.

Answer (score 7):

Check out NSJSONSerialization, makes taking dictionaries and arrays into json plain string format a breeze.

Generating json data
    NSDictionary *mydict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: ....

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

And changing this back :

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Doesn't get much simpler than that, and you don't need any external libraries or settings. Built right in

Comment: Thanks for this solution, maybe JSONKit can be an alternative if the iOS Target is under 5.x

Comment: Yes. I use SBJSON. Works like a charm

Comment: Only JSON is the ugliest representation of anything on earth. Bulky, ineffective, slow... There's another text representation on the Mac, much preferable, which is the .plist XML, which is also the native persistence format for NSDictionary when you [dict saveToFile:] or [dict saveToURL:withError] and later [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:] etc.